# Server Send Code 521 While SSH running well

Tags: linux, php-fpm, centos8

I would like to ask a question regarding my server problem. I have no idea why it sent 521 code while resources is still fine. I think there is misconfiguration. I am using default of Webuzo panel. Nothing changed. I think the problem leads from php-fpm

```
request_slowlog_timeout = 5s
slowlog = var/log/php-fpm-dsimlife.logs
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 0
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 20
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10
request_terminate_timeout = 120s
php_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
php_flag[log_errors] = off
php_flag[short_open_tag] = off
php_value[disable_functions] = 
php_value[error_log] = 
php_value[error_reporting] = 
rlimit_files = 131072
rlimit_core = unlimited
catch_workers_output = yes
security.limit_extensions = FALSE 
env[HOSTNAME] = \$HOSTNAME
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

FYI, I am using Dual Xeon E5-2670 @2.60 Ghz 32GB server, and here is my php-fpm log

```
[20-Mar-2023 01:13:41] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 502345, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1com/api.php' (request: "POST /api.php?f=syncAccount") executing too slow (5.824632 sec), logging
[20-Mar-2023 01:13:42] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 502462, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1com/api.php' (request: "POST /api.php?f=getCompany") executing too slow (5.300816 sec), logging
[20-Mar-2023 01:13:42] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 502450, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1com/api.php' (request: "POST /api.php?f=citizenActivity") executing too slow (6.625257 sec), logging
[20-Mar-2023 01:13:42] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 502348, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1com/api.php' (request: "POST /api.php?f=getCompany") executing too slow (5.166035 sec), logging
[20-Mar-2023 01:13:59] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 502566, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1com/api-admin.php' (request: "GET /api-admin.php?f=dailyTask&password=@bobby123@") executing too slow (6.047916 sec), logging
[20-Mar-2023 01:14:07] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 502592, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1com/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork&password=@bobby123@") executing too slow (5.230719 sec), logging
```

Here is my error log

```
2023/03/20 00:34:56 [error] 487375#0: *73 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.70.189.120, server: id1.dsimlife.com, request: "POST /api.php?f=getCompanyLicense HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/usr/local/apps/php74/var/fpm-dsimlife.sock:", host: "id1.dsimlife.com"
2023/03/20 00:34:56 [error] 487375#0: *235 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.162.128, server: id1.dsimlife.com, request: "POST /api.php?f=getCompanyWarehouse HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/usr/local/apps/php74/var/fpm-dsimlife.sock:", host: "id1.dsimlife.com"
2023/03/20 00:34:56 [error] 487375#0: *296 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.70.142.115, server: id1.dsimlife.com, request: "POST /api.php?f=getCompany HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/usr/local/apps/php74/var/fpm-dsimlife.sock:", host: "id1.dsimlife.com"
2023/03/20 00:34:56 [error] 487375#0: *294 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.38.172, server: id1.dsimlife.com, request: "POST /api.php?f=getCompanyWorkplace HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/usr/local/apps/php74/var/fpm-dsimlife.sock:", host: "id1.dsimlife.com"
2023/03/20 00:34:56 [error] 487375#0: *290 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.170.239, server: id1.dsimlife.com, request: "POST /api.php?f=getCompanyPO HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/usr/local/apps/php74/var/fpm-dsimlife.sock:", host: "id1.dsimlife.com"
2023/03/20 00:34:56 [error] 487375#0: *292 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.38.224, server: id1.dsimlife.com, request: "POST /api.php?f=getWorkplace HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/usr/local/apps/php74/var/fpm-dsimlife.sock:", host: "id1.dsimlife.com"
2023/03/20 00:34:56 [error] 487375#0: *288 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.70.147.134, server: id1.dsimlife.com, request: "POST /api.php?f=getCompanyWarehouse HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/usr/local/apps/php74/var/fpm-dsimlife.sock:", host: "id1.dsimlife.com"
```

And here is based on my htop

[htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1S8P.png)

I really appreciate any answers regarding, I have been figured out for almost 8 hours and there is no change. I also use the calculator here: https://spot13.com/pmcalculator/ [which indicates how much to set php-fpm based on our server and script usage] but it is still does not work.

Comment: You will have to check your logs. You don't include enough information for any guesses from us...

Comment: which log to check?

Comment: Access log and error log is a good place to start

Comment: added for error log, anyway I am trying to find out what does "WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 502348" means. Does the script would be terminated?

Comment: is that a http 521 error? if so https://http.dev/521

Comment: Sure 521 error, I am unsure about that but I checked the SSH it works fine.